# How do I remove an old rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I started rebasing on another branch and decided to forget about that issue for a while and move on to a different branch.

The issue I am currently working on has nothing to do with the current

When I do `git status` I get:

```
You are currently rebasing branch 'my-old-branch'
(all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

This has nothing to do with what I am currently working on and I'd like to get rid of this rebase situation.

How do I remove the current `rebase`?

Comment: How did you switch to a different branch while rebasing? Did you use `git checkout -f <BRANCH>`? To answer your question, use `git rebase --abort` to stop rebase.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I just did `git checkout master`, `git checkout -b 'new branch'`... At the time I had forgotten I has started a `rebase`.... `--abort` worked great thank you.

Comment: What version of `Git` do you use that allows you to switch branches while rebase is in progress?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk git version 2.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git rebase --abort` to exit the rebase process.

Answer (score 2):

During a rebase git stores working files in `.git/rebase-*` directories.
`git rebase --abort` will delete these and checkout the original branch you were on.

If you only want just to get rid of the rebase and do not touch repo state - you can just `rm -rf .git/rebase-*`